# How to reinstall a apt-get dist-upgrade?

Tags: installation, package-management, dist-upgrade

I already have the latest version of Ubuntu 12.04.1. I want to reinstall every package again (a dist-upgrade reinstall). How do i do that?

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` only works one time. I want to reinstall again (to fix some things I broke in ubuntu).

Answer (score 3):

**For broken packages**

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

**Reinstall package**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall <package name>
```

**Note**

If the problem of a broken package still exist the solution is to edit the dpkg status file manually.

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block of information about it** and save the file.